# How to remove virus in windows 7?

Tags: virus

My pc have virus i seen one at download folder that named "files"
And Another virus that i seen in extranal storage like pendrive and sdcard it named "www.cricketscore"
or something like that. so, how to remove them ?

Comment: You could find answers [here](https://superuser.com/search?q=how+to+remove+a+virus) or follow [this instructions by Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/threats/how-to-get-rid-of-a-computer-virus)

Comment: I was using kaspersky Internet security it found some viruses then it asked to reboot after reboot it stopped working  then some of other software stopped working i tried to reinstall them but they failed to reinstall so is there any other way to remove virus without antivirus

Answer (score -1):

1. Open an antivirus like the Microsoft Security Essentials and perform a system scan.
2. If that doesn't work, try to download kaspersky recovery disk here and perform a system scan https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-rescue-disk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).